# Jquery selecting via data link

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have 10 images with a data-link attribute and want to get the current page path and select the one which matches

```
 var pathname = window.location.pathname;
current = $(".slide img").data('link', pathname);
console.log(current);
```

This is what I have so far, but it returns no results.

Answer (score 2):

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
current = $(".slide img[data-link='"+ pathname +"']"); // get the image with pathname
console.log(current);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) returns the *stored* data value, it does not select any elements. Instead, you could use the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
current = $(".slide img[data-link='" + pathname + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the value of `data-link` attributes instead of selecting the element, you can use use `filter` method.

```
var $current = $(".slide img").filter(function() {
   return $(this).data('link') === pathname;
});
```